# Sipdroid - Cannot change package name

Tags: android, sipdroid

I modify sipdroid for my voip app in android. Everything is ok but when i change package name "org.sipdroid.sipua", i cannot register for any server (rollback to name org.sipdroid.sipua and it work fine). Awww What wrong with this name???

Comment: I would guess that it depends on something in the org.sipdroid.sipua package that it cannot access when it's no longer in that package

Comment: you found a solution for this???   i have the same problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

i faced this situation and I have a solution which as follows

In this package name "org.sipdroid.sipua" right click on and select refactor =>Rename. And then go to manifest and edit this package name "org.sipdroid.sipua" as "XXX.YYYYY.ZZZ". Then the package name as changed as your wish. and one thing is it will affect all your other packages. you need to change based on your changed package name.

Answer (score 0):

IT IS VERY SIMPLE,please change the package name in Settings.java. YES, that's it. I am success.

`private final String sharedPrefsPath = "/data/data/org.sipdroid.sipua/shared_prefs/";`

change to:
`private final String sharedPrefsPath = "/data/data/org.yourpackage.sipua/shared_prefs/";`

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with `Preference Activity` used in storing the settings. If you see the files which use Preference you will have to update them with the new package name.

Answer (score 0):

well i did solve the problem of changing package name of sipdroid . and i am at success..

what you have to is . Change your package name in manifest file. and all other packages in src . with same as your package name in manifest file . after that also change path of shared prefs in settings.java file . after that you need also change the package name in sipdroid.xml and at last go to prefrences.xml there is also a reference given in this file for target package change it too .. after changing all packages there comes a time for jni file . the package which names like org.sipdroid.net.impl change it too it will effect osnetworksystem.cpp file change package names on methods with underscore . now everything will fix up . clean the project and run . it will connect to servers as well as package name also changed . cheers :-)